# Convert Apache command to nginx (FilesMatch)

Tags: apache, nginx, code-conversion

How to block viewing certain types of files through a browser to configure Nginx?

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the NginX version:

```
location ~ \.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$ {
  deny all;
}
```